# Is it possible to declare a class member both const/non-const?

Tags: c++, class, constants

I have a class that can take both a non-const pointer or a const pointer as arguments to its overloaded constructors. In my particular case, I need to instantiate an object of this class from both `const` and `non-const` methods of class `T`, but it fails from const methods, as it can't assign the const pointer to `foo` .

```
myClass() {
public:
    myClass(T* v);
    myClass(const T* v);
    // ...
    T* foo;
    // ...
}
```

Is it possible to assign the argument in both constructors to `foo`? If so, what would be the correct syntax?

EDIT:

In a more specific case, I have a class `myClass` that wraps around `std::vector` and allows to me to directly access subsets of a vector through a nested class `mySubset`:

```
 template<typename _type>
myClass() {
    std::vector<_type> data;
public:
    class mySubset(){
        myClass<type>* foo;
    public:
        mySubset(myClass<_type>* _in) { foo = _in; };
        mySubset(const myClass<_type>* _in) { foo = _in; /* error */ };
        // ...
    }
    // ...
    myClass();
    // ...
    void mySubset method() { return mySubset(this); };;
    void mySubset const_method const() { return mySubset(this); /* error */ };
    // ...
}
```

The code within is irrelevant -basically `mySubset` allows to both read and write to specific vector positions. While I'm able to achieve what I want with separate const and non-const nested classes, I was looking for a way to do this with a single return type.

Comment: Can you make a five or six line program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Depends on context. Please add context to get an answer. You can [`const_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) away the `const`, but then you run the risk of modifying a `T` that should not be modified. Whoever made it `const` may have had darn good reason to do so. If you hold the `T` and never modify it `const T* foo;` might be your best friend.

Comment: Change the class member to `const T* foo`

Comment: Simple answer is: **There can not be two members with the same name.** You need to use different name *(see example below)* when you need both, the const and non-const version. There are a few possible cases when you would need such a construct, but I think, that there are also other possible ways to solve this problem. It all depends on the context/requested functions. It can be done with only const member, or using another *(child class)* that can use the non-const version. To get a meaningful answer, please add more details of your problem and context.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a more detailed example

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have to reconsider your design since you can't initialize a `T*` with a `const T*` lvalue, without `const_cast` which should be avoided unless you're really really sure, (since it invokes an undefined behavior if you try to modify a const pointer after casting away its constness)

Instead, you could use template type deduction for `const` and `non const`

```
template <typename T>
class myClass {
public:
    //myClass(T* v):foo(v) { }
    myClass( T* v):foo(v)
    {
    }
    // ...
    T* foo;
    // ...
};
```

Then,

```
int a =42;
const int* p1 = &a;
int *p2 = &a;

myClass  X1(p1); //C++17 auto type deduction or use myClass<const int> X1(p1)
myClass  X2(p2);
```

Comment: That's one way to achieve that, but seems overkill to use templates as I only need to define it for 2 types

Answer (score 0):

You could using `const_cast` in your `const T*` constructor, but typically you shouldn't.

`const T*` means "point to a constant value T", and you store a "pointer to a T".  If you do a const cast, you could end up modifying a value which shouldn't be modified.  If you aren't going to modify `foo`, just declare it `const T*` and just use the single `const T*` constructor.

I'd check to see if this is a design issue.  A lot of the times these scenarios appear:
(1) Where you're storing a pointer to something as non-const when it should be const.  Typically this is because you're accessing values in another object and you should be passing the object as a (possibly const) reference at each use site rather than storing a pointer to it.
(2) When you really want to store a copy of an object, in which case you just keep a regular `T` and pass it in as `const T&` in the constructor.
(3) You're dealing with raw C-style strings and want to copy the contents into your own buffer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use parameterized-type (template) class as @P0W's answer, it is not possible you can use only one pointer to accept all constant and non-constant pointer type. You need another constant pointer type to accept only `const <your another class> *` in your wrapper class. 
Below code works after you have two separate pointer types in wrapper class which you may not like.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class SomeObject {
public:
    SomeObject(){}
    explicit SomeObject(int i):testVal(i){}
private:
    int testVal;
};

class PtWrapper {
public:
    PtWrapper(SomeObject *pso);
    PtWrapper(const SomeObject *cpso);
private:
    SomeObject *pSO;
    const SomeObject *cpSO;
};



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    SomeObject so(133);
    SomeObject *pso = &so;
    const SomeObject cso(166);
    const SomeObject *cpso = &cso;
    PtWrapper pw1(pso);
    PtWrapper pw2(cpso);
    return 0;
}

PtWrapper::PtWrapper(SomeObject *pso) :pSO(pso){

}

PtWrapper::PtWrapper(const SomeObject *cpso):cpSO(cpso){}
```